# Getting matrix from polygon attribute table that represents vertex couples using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, array

How can I get a matrix from a polygon attribute table that represents polygon vertex couples?

What I want is something like this :

A = [ (A1,B1) , (A1,C1) , (B1,C1)
      (A2,B2) , (A2,C2) , (B2,C2)
      ....    ,  ....   ,    ....
      ...     ,   ....  ,  ....  ]      ]

[image]

Comment: How/where do you want the results? As a list of lists?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly something similar to below may help.

I created two new fields, Fields_1_2 and Fields_1_3, both of which are text data types. I then ran the following Python script in the Field Calculator on the Fields_1_2 field:

```
str(!Field1!) + ", " + str(!Field2!)
```

And the following Python script on the Fields_1_3 field:

```
str(!Field1!) + ", " + str(!Field3!)
```

The results looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [da.SearchCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) and [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD

```
import arcpy
from itertools import combinations

feature_class = r'C:\data.gdb\featureclass'
fields = ['POINT A', 'POINT B', 'POINT C']

all_combinations = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        all_combinations.append(list(combinations(row,2)))
```

Will give you:

```
>>all_combinations
[[(1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 5)], 
 [(43, 4), (43, 6), (4, 6)]
...]
```

Comment: @baccaribilel nice, could you accept my answer with the checkbox?